# Separating seaborn barplot with two colors

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have the following dataset:

```
words = ['upvoted', 'upvote', 'f***', 'reimer', 'feminists', 'censorship',
       'wet', '0001f914', 'turtle', '0001f602', 'vegans', 'thumbnail',
       'lobby', 'mods', 'removed', 'bitches', 'saffron', 'broadband',
       'hitler', 'ass', 'deleted', 'u', 'tits', 'cheating', 'antifa',
       'iâ', 'â', 'itâ', 'donâ', 'edit', 'thatâ', 'isnâ', 'doesnâ',
       'didnâ', 'canâ', 'youâ', 'theyâ', 'eli5', 'weâ', 'arenâ', 'thereâ',
       'hi', 'wouldnâ', '½ï', 'whatâ', 'ï', '½', 'wasnâ', 'wonâ',
       'eclipse'] 

coefs = [ 1.00157191,  0.95931338,  0.92066619,  0.86347946,  0.83977936,
        0.83912351,  0.83482245,  0.8148754 ,  0.79982483,  0.79402501,
        0.7687297 ,  0.76765479,  0.76096785,  0.75893433,  0.75177131,
        0.74486391,  0.73244163,  0.71302245,  0.70449932,  0.70346844,
        0.69737316,  0.67902944,  0.6746799 ,  0.67338842,  0.6678747 ,
       -2.83723585, -2.82874502, -2.59032368, -2.52985115, -2.1811188 ,
       -1.87094025, -1.66191757, -1.64283967, -1.62282287, -1.61855926,
       -1.55062817, -1.54397537, -1.39775882, -1.3492324 , -1.30638486,
       -1.29859752, -1.14761071, -1.0673105 , -1.06272808, -1.02998239,
       -0.96635257, -0.94262438, -0.91244845, -0.90765028, -0.87274524]
```

and I would like to make a barplot with two colors, one for negative and one for positive values of the coefficient.

My efforts have lead me to:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)})
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)
g = sns.barplot(words,coefs, palette =sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, n=50, center = "dark"))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

But even here I cannot trully separate them, it only makes a scale of colors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand seaborn coloring a bit wrongly :)

Seaborn's color schemes are repeating. For example, let's use this palette:

`sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, n=20, center = "dark")`

We will get this plot:

[image]

If you don't want repeating effect, you should specify a `hue` for each bar (if you will not do it, `y` will be used as `hue`):

`colors = [1 if c >= 0 else 0 for c in coefs]`

and send it to your bar plot:

```
g = sns.barplot(
    x=words,
    y=coefs,
    hue=colors, # Here I am!
    palette=sns.color_palette() # Default palette is far better for it
)
```

So you will get what you need:

[image]

Comment: This solution is not the best, using `hue` will move each bar to the left or right to make room for the different hues. So all bar will be decentered with respect to their tick. This is quite noticeable on barplots with not so many x ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @vurmux answer, using `hue` will decenter your bars, which is noticeable in smaller plots. You can alternatively just build a list of colors and pass it to the palette argument, like this

```
colors = ['g' if c >= 0 else 'r' for c in coefs]
g = sns.barplot(
    x=words,
    y=coefs,
    palette=colors
)
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution, thanks